# how to query for items not in a set of id's - cleaning up data

Tags: sql

Say for example I have the following foreign key ids:

```
 10437 
 10476 
 13212 
 13215
```

and I want to find one of them that has been deleted from the primary table ie which of these are missing from this set? How would I do this? I'm assumign some variation of an `in` statement.

thx in advance

**edit #1**

So to rephrase the above, I want somethign like:

```
TABLE
id 
10437 
13215


select something from items where id not in (10437, 10476, 13212, 13215)

would return:
10476 
13212
```

The numbers are on the order of hundreds of items so just want to delete the orphaned records and it's not a traditional foreign key relatioinship so an outer join won't work.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: curious why the downvotes? seems like a legitimate questioin

Comment: I guess because you didn't do a basic search of the SQL information available online. Just like the in statement, there is the not in statement... so you didn't look hard enough before asking. It should have been something obvious to find quickly.

Comment: a standard not in won't satisfy what I'm trying to do to best of my knowledge

Comment: can you rephrase what you're asking properly then? what we understood is that you just want to find the rows in a table which have a foreign key to rows in another table that might have been deleted.

Comment: I've rephrased it as simply as I can

Comment: You didnt give much extra information honestly! You just gave the same numbers again and then said its not a traditional foreign key relationship. In what ways isn't it a traditional FK? Why don't you put the real table structure there, and specify exactly what fields you have related to each other.

Comment: yeah, the structure wouldn't have been much help. thx for answer, I upvoted u.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You can use the `NOT IN` predicate like so:</strike>

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName
WHERE ReferenceId NOT IN(10437, 10476, 13212, 13215);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eecf3/1)

**Update:** If you want the Id's that exist, use the `IN` predicate:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName 
WHERE ReferenceId IN (10437, 10476, 13212, 13215);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eecf3/11)

**Update 2:** To clear this up, you want the list of ids from the list of ids that you have that doesn't exist in the table. It the same idea, but the other way

```
SELECT FROM (list of ids) WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT referenceid from Table);
```

Not thist:

```
SELECT FROM Table WHERE id not in (list of ids ) will give you the other list;
```

Because this will give the list of ids from the table that doesn't exist in the list of ids.

You can do this like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
( 
    SELECT 10437 id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10476
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 13212
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 13215
) t1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT referenceid FROM YourTableName);
```

Or with a `RIGHT JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT t2.Id
FROM YourTableName t1 
RIGHT JOIN
( SELECT 10437 id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 10476
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 13212
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 13215
 ) t2 ON t1.ReferenceID = t2.id
WHERE t1.referenceid IS NULL;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2e25/10)

Both should return:

```
10476 
13212
```

Comment: so, that will return the other 10,000 rows but would like something like that

Comment: @timpone - What do you mean by the other 10000 it will return only the rows with ids not in this list of ids

Comment: so I'm cleaning up some data, these are stale data so a foreign key that doesn't exist in the primary table (ie dirty data). I got this as a dump from a partner. I'd like to delete these orphaned records. So if I just select from the primary table like in your query, I'll get back all the other records when all I want is the one that doesn't exit.

Comment: pretty sure it's a left outer join but would think it could be done easier

Comment: @timpone - Can you please give me an example of how is this not working for you? and what is the desired data? For example, in the example fiddle above the table contains the ids: `10400, 10339, 10476, 13212`. And you want the ids that doesn't exist in the list `10437, 10476, 13212, 13215` Right? This give you the rows with the ids `10400` and `103991. Isn't that what you are looking for? If no what is the desired output in the example?

Comment: in your example, I'd want to return: 10437,13215; the values in your set in the in statement that do NOT exist

Comment: @timpone - Sorry I missed that. Just use the `IN` instead of `NOT IN`. See my edit.

Comment: Thx, so I get that that's going to return the "good" ones. But I really want to figure out the not good ones. Does that make sense? Basically the difference so that I can just go in and delete these 'orphaned' records.

Comment: @timpone - Sorry I missed this up. See my edit please. And don't delete any data. Just select for now

Comment: @timpone why doesn't my answer work then? I gave you a full example of how to get the orphaned records.

Comment: Cool, that totally works! I was able to do this: `select * from (select global_id from globals_lists where list_id=77) t1 where t1.global_id not in (select global_id from items);` and it got me back what I needed. Great Job!!! thx so much! Just need to test a few things out but I think that is it.

Comment: No problem - not that familiar with that syntax; I don't get all the down votes; actually googled for a good 15 minutes but everything was a simple `in` and not the reverse

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your-table where id not in (your-list-of-ids)
```

Depending on what database you're using `your-list-of-ids` can be a nested query like:

`select id from your-other-table`

**MORE CLEARLY**

`select id from your-primary-table` gives you all the IDs in your primary table.

```
select * from your-secondary-table where foreign_key_id not in (select id from your-primary-table)
```

gives you the rows in the secondary table whose foreign keys do not exist any more in the primary table.

Comment: so I need to limit to just that set, a query like that will return the full set that are not in those few numbers.

Comment: you already know how to do an 'in' statement, and now you know how to do a 'not in', isn't it simply the case of combining them with an 'AND' now?

Comment: I've added an edit. I don't think combining an in and not in will get me what I am looking for. basically, it's not a simple relatioship. I can only start with the secondary table.

Comment: I don't know why you are thinking that it will return everything. it will not. It will only return the orphaned records.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.foreign_key_field from table_with_foreign_key as t1 
left join table_with_primary_key as t2 on t2.id = t1.foreign_key_field 
where  t2.id is null
```

syntax depends on sql dialect

Comment: thx kris, I wish it were this simple but this relationship has been denormalized so I'd like some other way that doing a left outer join

Comment: What does it mean 'denormalized'? It is not necessary to have relationship between tables to use 'left join' ... If I understand you correctly

Comment: Which database you are using? I tried this query on postgres..

Comment: Y, MySQL 5.5; so denormalize means that your intentionally disobyeing Database Normalization http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization . Two common reasons: 1. performance 2. creating more flexible relationships (this is used heavily in rails)